# How to make a payment by credit card Visa and Mastercard on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an application on the flutter.  I need to be able to pay by Visa and Mastercard.  Is there any way to do this or is there another way to pay?

Comment: There is an API called [Stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_sdk).

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of available Payment Processor APIs that you can choose from. [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) is one of the popular ones that you can use. Here's an active [Stripe Flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) that you can check out.

Update: Flutter has just released their first-party payments API: [`pay`](https://pub.dev/packages/pay). On Android, Google Pay is used; while Apple Pay is used for iOS.